# how to pass checkbox value from map function in react js

Tags: reactjs

**Code:**

```
var list = this.state.data.map(function(value, idx){
  return(
    <ul style = {common}>
      <li><input type="checkbox" value={value.id} onChange={this.displayAlert.bind(this, value.id)}/></li>
      <li>{value.id}</li>
      <li>{value.Name}</li>
      <li>{value.points}</li>
      <li>{value.nationality}</li>
    </ul>
  )
}, this)

return (
  <div>
    <div>{list}</div>
    <button onClick ={  this.deleteHandler.bind(this)}>delete</button>
  </div>
)
```